# Is it possible to change a section of URL text when using IMPORTXML to a reference cell

Tags: google-sheets-formula

So I am trying to use IMPORTXML to pull data for stocks, but I want to simplify it with referencing a cell to change the stock name in the URL.

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/aapl/financials/balance-sheet","/html/body/div[3]/div[6]/div/div[2]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/div/span")
```

So is there a way to make the "aapl" part of the URL reference to a cell that has a new stocks ticker to change the URL to a that new stocks balance sheet?

I am very new to this, sorry if my question doesn't make sense or is dumb. Thanks for any help provided.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/"&A1&"/financials/balance-sheet","/html/body/div[3]/div[6]/div/div[2]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/div/span")
```

Change A1 with the cell you want

Comment: Thank you so much. Your reference worked, but I had to remove the aapl ticker and just use "&A1&" and it worked. Big thanks friend for the help.

Comment: He, I thought I had erased it. I'll edit it now. I'm glad it was useful and you worked it out!